# Unity : How do I change a Shader Graph's property (float) over time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

As seen below, I created a shader effect and added a Vector1 property called "Visibility", where if set to 1 nothing happens but as it progresses to 0 the shader effect comes into play and becomes visible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZFbO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrE8F.jpg)

My issue is finding a way to reduce the **Visibility** property from 1 to 0 over time, in the span of 2 seconds it should go from 1 to 0. I know how to change the value of the "Visibility" property through code using SetFloat, like this:

```
 if (door.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = changeDisolve)
     {
         changeDisolve.SetFloat("Visibility", 0.0f);
     }
```

But i want the value to progress to 0 via a 'duration', so i tried using Mathf.Lerp as seen below-which did not work either:

```
 if (door.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = changeDisolve)
     {
         float changeVisibility = Mathf.Lerp(1f, 0f, 3f);
         changeDisolve.SetFloat("Visibility", changeVisibility);
     }
```

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong or how to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the code to be called each X Seconds you should use `InvokeRepeating`. You could also start `InvokeRepeating` the moment you enter a BoxCollider with `OnTriggerEnter()` or the moment you leave a BoxCollider with `OnTriggerExit()` etc, but you can't use `Update`.

You can use `CancelInvoke();` to stop all `InvokeRepeating` calls. In this case after your `shaderValue` has reached 0 or less.

```
// Starting at the start of the game after Awake()
// the shader will be changed every 0.2 seconds

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private shaderValue = 1f;
    private float change = 0.1f;

    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("ChangeShader", 0.1f, 0.2f);
    }

    void Changeshader()
    {
         if (shaderValue <= 0f) {
             CancelInvoke();
         }

         else if (door.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = changeDisolve) {
             shaderValue -= change;
             changeDisolve.SetFloat("Visibility", shaderValue);
         }
    }
}
```

You could also use an `IEnumerator`, which makes it possible to call `WaitForSeconds` which will then wait that amount and after the specified delay has been finished continue with the rest of the code.

You could also use `OnTriggerEnter()` or `OnTriggerExit()` instead of `Start()`.

```
// Starting in Update
// the shader will be changed every 0.2 seconds

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private shaderValue = 1f;
    private float change = 0.1f;
    private float delay = 0.2f;

    void Start()
    {
         StartCouroutine(ChangeShader());
    }

    IEnumerator Changeshader()
    {
         while (shaderValue > 0f){

             yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);             

             if (door.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = changeDisolve) {
                 shaderValue -= change;
                 changeDisolve.SetFloat("Visibility", shaderValue);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tiny nitpick: Instead of beingHandled I would use Coroutine runningCo variable. Then start with runningCo = StartCoroutine() and as last coroutine line runningCo = null.

Comment: I edited my IEnuemerator code is it correct now, never used the Coroutine variable before so I'm unsure.

Comment: You should change - if (shaderValue > 0f && runninCo == null). BTW is there a reason why you call the coroutine every 0.5 secs instead of looping inside of it?

Comment: No you could theoretically change it if you don't want it to happen in Update and call it that way over Start or OnTriggerEnter instead.

Comment: Changed the IEnumerator function, thanks for the tipps.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but none of answers worked as i intended them too. I'm not trying to change a shader every 0.5 seconds, i'm simply trying to change a property on a material that is a slider that goes from 1 to 0. OnTrigger i want the slider property to go from where it is-1 to 0 in the span of two seconds. So i should be able to see it go from 1,0.9,0.8,0.7 and so on till it reaches 0 in 2 seconds. if that makes sense.

Comment: You know that you can simply change the delay variable to 0.2 seconds and then you'll get to 0 in 2 seconds? 0.5 seconds was just and example because you didn't provide any of the timings you wanted.

Comment: I tried using the IEnumerator example you sent but I can't seem to run "StartCoroutine(ChangeShader);" in Start(). It says that i cannot convert from 'method group' to a string.

Comment: Yeah sry i got a typo it should be `StartCoroutine(ChangeShader());`

Comment: Thanks for replying Mat. Okay so the code worked without errors but it didn't work as intended.
If i'm understanding your code, the 'float change' variable should be deducting the shaderValue variable by -0.1 and repeating itself as long as shaderValue is > 0, in the span of float delay. But for some reason the code is changing the "Visibility" to -0.1 instead of deducting. So it instantly becomes -0.1 and then stops.

Comment: yeah sorry my mistake had another tpyo. Right now I set shaderValue to -0.1 immediatly instead of decreasing shaderValue. I'll edit the code again to `shaderValue -= change;` which is the same as `shaderValue = shaderValue - change;`

Comment: It finally worked! Thank you so much. I've been at this for 3 days and i can finally rest easy. You're a legend. I'm off to start reading up on IEnumerator and Coroutines.

Comment: If it works, then please mark my answer as the correct solution (green checkmark). Thanks in advance.